# Could not build wheels for cryptography which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, windows, pycharm

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD "-IE:\Python Project\PropertyTax\venv\i
nclude" -IC:\Users\pc1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\include -IC:\Users\pc1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Bu
ildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Progra
m Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\
winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /Tcbuild\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\_openssl.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\R
elease\_openssl.obj
  _openssl.c
  build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\_openssl.c(498): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'openssl/opensslv.h': No such file or directory
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.24.28314\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

  ----------------------------------------

  Failed building wheel for cryptography
  Running setup.py clean for cryptography`enter code here`
Failed to build cryptography
Could not build wheels for cryptography which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

Comment: did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 4):

try

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade --no-use-pep517 cryptography
```

this solved it for me on Ubuntu:18.04 on armhf

other suggested to upgrade pip setuptools and wheel to latest versions with:

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
```

that did not help in my case, maybe in yours

Comment: ERROR: Disabling PEP 517 processing is invalid: project specifies a build backend of setuptools.build_meta in pyproject.toml